# Run chromium with kiosk with auto-refreshing webpage (Spotify Jukebox)

Tags: raspbian, python, chromium, kiosk

I know I can run Chromium full screen based off of this [tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-kiosk/?unapproved=10279&moderation-hash=ed67b8c0190c22fbe7e955c79944f63e#comment-10279), in kiosk mode, but I'm wondering what would I need to do to set up my pi up so that instead of just running one webpage on startup, it could change the web page that is being displayed every time the song changes, by grabbing a link from a Python script I wrote. The script gets the album art of the current song playing on Spotify (it returns a link to an image host that looks like [this](https://i.scdn.co/image/f1cd8b95970f06d4593d0cc8822011b4c0bebde4)).  I'm not very familiar with Linux so I'm not sure what this would look like.  Is there a way to accomplish this within Python? Thanks.

Comment: A link can be useful, but many users won't go through a whole tutorial to understand what you're trying to do. Could you please edit your question and add: 1) the steps you're following or 2) the code you're trying to modify and need help with.

Comment: Can you please split your sentence into more than one?

Comment: @David  Ok, got it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not writing your code for you, but this answer should put you on the right track.

1. start chromium and specify a URL:

`chromium-browser https://i.scdn.co/image/f1cd8b95970f06d4593d0cc8822011b4c0bebde4`

The python program could start chromium using `os.system` or something similar.

2. If it were up to me, I would not use chromium to display the images. Instead I would use something lower-level:
   `wget https://i.scdn.co/image/f1cd8b95970f06d4593d0cc8822011b4c0bebde4 -O image.png`
   This would download your image and save it to /home/pi/image.png.
   You could then preview that image with image viewer:
   `gpicview image.png`
   Unfortunately image viewer won't open in fullscreen from the command line, so I would use `mirage`.
   `sudo apt install mirage`
   Once it's installed you can open the image in fullscreen with mirage:
   `mirage -f image.png`